# How to refresh the streambuild on setState in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, builder, stream-builder

Looking at this code

```
    StreamBuilder<Member?>(
                stream: UserController().readUser(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Container(
                      child: SmallText(
                          text: "An error occured while processing this page"),
                    );
                  } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    if (snapshot.data == null) {
                      return Container(
                        child: SmallText(text: "No data to fetch"),
                      );
                    } else {
                      var cuser = snapshot.data!;

               
               _updateLimit(cuser.id, cuser.spinDailyLimit); // Inside onTap event
}
                  }
                }
    );
```

Here Once the page is loaded, I consume **snapshot.data** more than once without reloading the page.

Like, onTap I subtract 1 from snapshot.data.limit, but here it works perfect on first onTap why the rest will will still carry the data when the page was first loaded

Example

```
  Future<void> _updateLimit(String id, int? spinDailyLimit) async {
    final dataini = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(id);
    print(" limit ${spinDailyLimit}");
    var sd = spinDailyLimit! - 1;
    await dataini.update({
      'spinDailyLimit': sd,
    });
```

I want to keep decreasing the number without page reload. I tried setState but it didn't work, please I need help.